# Transform GET request to POST request to load generated PDF file

Tags: javascript, php, post, get

In an html page I have a button that loads a generated pdf:

```
<button onclick='getpdf()'>GET PDF</button>

<script>
function getpdf(){
  data={
    var1: 'var1',
    var2: 'var2'
  };
  window.open('genpdf.php?var1='+data['var1']+'&var2='+data['var2'], '_new');
}
</script>
```

genpdf.php is something like this:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];

$pdf = new PDF();

/* ......... */

$pdf->Output('D','generated.pdf');
?>
```

My question is:

How can I change my code to pass parameters with POST method?

**SOLUTION**

ADyson suggested me this solution:

```
<form id="pdf" action="genpdf.php" methon="POST" target="_new">
  <input type="hidden" name="var1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="var2" />
  <button onclick='getpdf()'>GET PDF</button>
</form>

<script>
function getpdf(){
  $("#pdf input[name=var1]").val('var1');
  $("#pdf input[name=var2]").val('var2');
  $("#pdf").submit();
}
</script>
```

and

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];

$pdf = new PDF();

/* ......... */

$pdf->Output('D','generated.pdf');
?>
```

and it works fine!

**BUT**

If I wanted to do that without the use of a form, how could I do?

Comment: One option: store the variables in a hidden field and make the button be part of a form (also containing those hidden fields) which posts back to genpdf when clicked.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you. But when I click the button, I have to put the right values in the hidden inputs before calling genpdf. How to do that?

Comment: Well, where do those values come from originally? Either you can add them into the hidden fields when the page is loaded, or if they're created later, you could intercept the form's submit event using JS, use then JS to put them in the hidden fields and then programmatically submit the form.

Comment: `If I wanted to do that without the use of a form, how could I do?`...you can programatically construct a form using JS, which never actually gets shown in your page. And then submit that. Or you can use AJAX - but if you're trying to download the PDF, with AJAX you'd need some extra steps when you receive the response because it won't trigger a file download action in the browser automatically. There are solutions you can read about online easily for achieving that, though, so it's not a big barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement without coding HTML then use following Javascript

```
var myform = document.createElement('form');
myform.style.display = "none";
myform.name='PdfGenOrSomethingElse';
myform.method='POST';
myform.action='genpdf.php';
myform.target='_blank';

var var1=document.createElement('input');
var1.type='text';
var1.name='var1';
var1.value='Put/update your value';

var var2=document.createElement('input');
var2.type='text';
var2.name='var2';
var2.value='Put/update your value';

myform.appendChild(var1);
myform.appendChild(var2);

document.body.appendChild(myform);
myform.submit();
```

Notice the form will not be displayed on the page. "display" property is set to "none".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any javascript function for this. Just use FORM element with action post:

```
<form action="genpdf.php" method="post" target="_blank">

    <input type="text" name="var1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="var2" value="" />

    <button type="submit ">GET PDF</button>
</form>
```

The don't forget to use $_POST instead of $_GET in your PHP script.

Comment: I have to update the values of var1 and var2 before submitting the form. So I need javascript.